# Embarcadero C++Builder error for __property on Android

Tags: c++, c++11, c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

In C++Builder 10.2 Tokyo, when compiling the following code for Win32 or Win64, it compiles ok:

```
class TRtpReceiver
{
    public:

        void __fastcall SetNext( RtpPacket *NewNext );
        RtpPacket * __fastcall GetNext();

        __property RtpPacket *Next = { read=GetNext, write=SetNext };

};
```

But when compiling for Android, I get this error:

> [bccaarm Error] StvSimpleRtp.h(73): non-object type 'ssize_t (int, void *, size_t)' is not assignable
>   [bccaarm Error] StvSimpleRtp.h(73): non-object type 'ssize_t (int, const void *, size_t)' is not assignable

Any ideas?

Comment: That error message doesn't really match the code shown. Is it possible that `SetNext` is also defined elsewhere in your project? If you change the names of your class methods, do you still get the same error? If so, [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero.